# Problems creating a static C++ library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

Greetings fellow programmers! I am trying to create a  C++ library to use in other projects. This library is to be a static library that will be linked to other projects.

Problem: The compiler doesn't seem to catch errors that it otherwise would if it were configured as an executable program under Project->Properties>General. In fact I purposely made a syntax error and the compiler
gave me a success regardless.

Is there a way to force the compiler to check everything while building a static lib?

Build Environment: Visual Studio 2010

EDIT: As it turns out, it was a rather simple, yet incredibly subtle mistake. It turns out that Visual studio was treating some of my .cpp files as header files. Because of this, the compiler was not running through the code at all (no one includes .cpp files). When adding files to the library, I must have accidentally selected header instead of C++ file. I thought Visual Studio would only rename the header file. I guess I was wrong!

Answer (score 4):

This is nonsensical. It cannot happen. What is probably happening is that you *think* that the compiler is compiling your source file, (the one with the syntax error,) but it does not. Perhaps you have not added your source file to your project.

(Then again, C++ has a pretty quirky syntax; I hope you are sure that what you made was in fact a syntax error, and not a syntactically valid language construct.)

Comment: +1 for C++'s syntax oddities. When one can write what's been called the "WTF operator" using `??!??!` (e.g. `do_something() ??!??! log_error();`) you have to make sure that an intentional syntax error is truly a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one project in the workspace (solution) like exe and lib, make sure you click on the exact one to build or set it as the startup project (showing up in bold letters) if you hit the F7 button.